# no version.py when install gizeh

Tags: python, pip

I tried to use pip to install gizeh, but it failed whilst installing cairo. So I installed cairo separately, and downloaded the repo and used this command to install it:

```
python c:\gizeh-master\setup.py install
```

But I get a

```
no 'version.py'
```

Error. What should I do to install this module without any problems? Is it even compatible with Python 3.5?

Comment: Why not create a `version.py` in the `gizeh` sub-directory? Or just download `version.py` from [here](https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh/tree/master/gizeh) and then retry the install command

Comment: The README on the [repo for gizeh](https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh/blob/master/README.rst) does claim that `Gizeh should work on any platform and with python 2 and 3.`, so hopefully the python version wouldn't be the problem.